# SED to replace text inside quotes

Tags: regex, sed

Assuming I have a text file where some lines are of this format:

```
%attr(750,user1,group1)  "/mydrive/mypath1/mypath2\winpath1\winpath2\file.xml"
```

What I wanna achieve is:

- touch only those lines which start with %attr
- on each of such lines find **the last** occasion of ".*" (including quotes)
- inside that last occasion replace all `\` to `/`

What is the proper syntax for **sed** utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can do the job easily:

```
awk -F '"' '/^%attr/ {gsub(/\\/, "/", $(NF-1))} 1' OFS='"' file
```

To change the original file:

```
awk -F '"' '/^%attr/ {gsub(/\\/, "/", $(NF-1))} 1' OFS='"' file > _tmp && mv _tmp file
```

Comment: Only lines starting with `%attr` like this `awk -F\" '/%attr/ {gsub(/\\/, "/", $(NF-1))} 1' file`

Comment: And it removes the `"`

Comment: Would sed be much more complicated? I tried that command and it just prints result out to the console, I'd rather modify existing file, what should I change?

Comment: @Alec: See the edited answer. sed unfortunately doesn't have lookaheads or non greedy regex flavor that's why awk is more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `sed '/\%attr/{s/\\/\//g}'`

Comment: This change the `\\`` anywhere in the line, not just in the quoted area. `"`